# Mongoose / MongoDB - Simple example of appending to a document object array, with a pre-defined schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-schema

For the sakes of simplicity, assuming these are my collection schemas:

```
var MessageDeliverySchema = new Schema({
    from   : { type : String },
    to     : { type : String },
    status : { type : String }
});

var Messages = mongoose.model('messages',
new Schema({
    id              : ObjectId,
    user            : { type:String },
    'sent-messages' : [MessageDeliverySchema]
}));
```

So each document in the collection *Messages* may have 4/5 *sent-messages* defined by the MessageDeliverySchema.

What I want to do is have an array of *sent-messages*, so each time a delivery receipt comes in I just update *Messages* and append another sent message.

What I've tried:

```
var delivered = {
from: 'foo',
to: 'bar',
status: 'delivered'
};

Message.update({_id: '5064aae4154cb34d14000001' },
        {$pushAll: { 'sent-messages' : delivered }} , {upsert:true}, function(err, data) { 

});

Message.update({_id: '5064aae4154cb34d14000001' },
         {$push: { 'sent-messages' : delivered }},{upsert:true}, function(err, data) { 
});
```

$pushAll, and $push, doesn't append a new object to *sent-messages*, instead it overwrites an existing message.

What I want to see is an array of sent messages e.g:

```
{
    'sent-messages': [
        {
            from: 'foo',
            to: 'bar',
            status: 'delivered'
        },
        {
            from: 'pippo',
            to: 'pippo',
            status: 'delivered'
        },
        {
            from: 'paul',
            to: 'smith',
            status: 'undelivered'
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `$push` is the right operator to use and your code worked fine when I tried it.  Each time I ran it a new `sent-messages` array element was added.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Ah, OK, so it wasn't overwriting the the existing message. I am getting the error: 'Cannot apply $push/$pushAll modifier to non-array'.

Comment: Meaning that the `sent-messages` property in that document that's already in the database is not an array so it can't be pushed to.  Perhaps you added that doc through some other means so it doesn't match your Mongoose schema.

Comment: Yes I added it without the $push, I'll answer my question below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error I was getting was: 'Cannot apply $push/$pushAll modifier to non-array'.

I added an object to the document like this:

```
    Message.update({_id: '5064aae4154cb34d14000001' },
           { 'sent-messages' : delivered }, function(err, data) { 
    });
```

And then tried to do a $push, which gave me the above error.

So I removed the document and used $push which had the desired effect.

For reference this is the correct way to append to an existing document, and the answer to my question:

```
Message.update({_id: '5064aae4154cb34d14000001' },
         {$push: { 'sent-messages' : delivered }},{upsert:true}, function(err, data) { 
});
```